# replace <h2> tags before strip_tags

Tags: strip-tags

I'm trying to replace the `<h2>` and `</h2>` tag from a string this way but it's not working:

```
    $desc = get_post_meta($post_id , 'desc', true);
    
    preg_replace("/<h2>/", '', $desc);
    preg_replace("/</h2>/", ' - ', $desc);
```

Then I like to the strip all other tags this way `strip_tags($desc)`

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
    $trash_h2_tags = array("<h2>", "</h2>");
    $desc = str_replace($trash_h2_tags, '', $desc);
```